# Ext js object to take the style of the target element

Tags: html, extjs

I have ExtJs 2.2

and I have this input in a JSP:

```
    <td class="myStyle" bgcolor="someColor"><div align="left">
    <input name="myInput" type="text" id="myInput" value="" size="30" maxlength="40">
    </div></td>
```

then i have this:

```
    Ext.onReady(function(){
       new Ext.form.NumberField({  
       allowDecimals: false,
       allowNegative: false,
       cls:'',
       emptyClass:'',
       emptyText:'',
       fieldClass:'',
       focusClass:'',
       invalidClass:'',
       invalidText:'',
       disableClass:'',
       grow: false,
       maxLenght: 40,
        applyTo: document.getElementById("myInput")
  });
 });
```

But, it changes the style that the input had...
is there a way to preserve the style from myInput ?

EDIT:

Also I noticed yesterday, that I was putting the Extjs input above the html input!..
So i change the HTML code to this:

```
    <td class="myStyle" bgcolor="someColor"><div align="left" id='myInputDiv'>
    </div></td>
```

and the extjs code to this:

```
    Ext.onReady(function(){
       new Ext.form.NumberField({  
       allowDecimals: false,
       allowNegative: false,
       cls:'',
       emptyClass:'',
       emptyText:'',
       fieldClass:'',
       focusClass:'',
       invalidClass:'',
       invalidText:'',
       disableClass:'',
       grow: false,
       maxLenght: 40,
               id: 'myInput',
               name: 'myInput',
        applyTo: document.getElementById("myInputDiv")
  });
 });
```

But, its still looking different to the other inputs in the page

Comment: Hi Carlos, can you please add the CSS that is missing in the element. Have you tried firefox + https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/ You can use the CSS view and see why is your element loosing the style.

Comment: There isn't a CSS affecting the HTML inputs.

Answer (score 1):

In ExtJs you can use  `Ext.select` to select the element and then apply the style that you want.

For example,  `Ext.select('.el').setStyle('color', 'green');` will apply the `color:green` property to all the elements with the class **.e1**.

Comment: Maybe what I want is impossible, what I want is the NumberField to look just like any of the other fields i have...

Comment: or, can I do something like:
Ext.select('.el').setStyle(document.getElementById('theElementIwantToTakeTheStyleFrom').getStyle())
?